# Website images performance: local folder or external source?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I just have finished building my first website. the website is fine but i noticed sometimes images load a bit slow and look slowly sliding down.all images on the website are derived from external sources.are they going to be loading quicker if i store and get those from local folder instead of using web source? or is there anyway i can load page after images finish loading?

Comment: They probably need to be file size optimized and there is lots of information available on optimizing in a web search.

Comment: Have you otpimized your images for web?

Comment: A good workflow I have is: -- Use correct format --> resize --> Compress --> Make jpegs progressive --> Host on CDN (if possible)

Answer (score 4):

Hosting images on the website itself rather than from an external source can bring speed benefits as HTTP connections can be re-used, but the benefits will be very minor, and if your images are all hosted on the same external source then that will have the same effect.

Optimizing your images for the web (by resizing them to an appropriate resolution for your website's target devices and compressing the images), however, can make a large difference to page load time.

Additionally, if you use many small images in your CSS stylesheet, you can encode them in base64 and include them inline with the stylesheet, which saves on HTTP requests but does increase the file size for the CSS document so is not good for large images.

Double-check that you have appropriate caching levels configure, and finally, consider using a CDN provider (eg. CloudFlare) who can cache your website in multiple locations around the world so the server is closer to the user. CDNs often also include other speed-improvement features such as automatic image compression.

Answer (score 1):

One good way of storing images is using public servers such as Flickr or Imgur. Another solution is to host it by yourself on a fast AWS S3 server or something with optimised file size and compressed in a proper manner.

Hope this helped.