# Is loading images locally faster than using external URLs in React app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image

I am trying to understand, and I'm new to this. If I deploy a react app and store the images in with in the React app will it effect the speed of React app? When loading for the first time will all images be downloaded on request? If that's the case it's good to go for external image?

External

```
  <img className="w-full rounded-lg" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1551650975-87deedd944c3ixlib=rb1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2574&q=80" alt="Sunset in the mountains"></img>
```

Internal

```
import gameImg from "../../assets/images/game.jpg";
```

as per this question: [Website images performance: local folder or external source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40959745/website-images-performance-local-folder-or-external-source) local images are good way. But is it the same case for the react app?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With a standard Crate React app, the behavior depends on the size image. as stated by the documentation on [Adding Images, Fonts, and Files](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/)

Images smaller than 10000 bytes and not ending in .svg are encoded to a data uri. This means they are embedded inside your JavaScript bundle, and are effectively downloaded directly when your application loads

For other sizes, react copies them to the static folder in the output directory. The first time the image is used, the browser will make an request to load the image. This is equivalent to locally storing image and the load time will be predictable.

With external image, your browser first has to resolve the domain name, make a new SSL connection, before they can make a request to download it, and you also have more privacy issues. But this is a valid solution for user provided content and dynamically updating images without rebuild.

Answer (score 1):

In both case, the browser will make a request to the web server.

The difference is that in the first case, the request is issued to a thirdparty external server (here images.unsplash.com).

In the second case, the request is issued to the same server that serve the application.

Both have pros and cons.

Personnaly i prefer serving images from the same server than application. I reserve outside server option for special case.

If you want to embed image in application, in clear avoid an extra request, you can embed your image in a base 64 encoded format, like this if you embedd it in a src HTML tag:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAlQAAAJUCAYAAADTmLgpAAABgmlDQ1BzUkdCIElFQzYxOTY2LTIuMQAAKJF1kc8rRFEUxz8GkV ..." />
```

Or like this if you embed this in CSS rule:

```
url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAA ... AAABJRU5ErkJggg==')
```

Of course, in this case, your application will be bigger, and the initial load can be longer. But if the usage is limited, this will don't make really changes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using Create React App (or something similar). At any rate, if you `console.log(gameImg)` you'll see that it gives you a URL just like an external image. Thus, if you create an `<img src={gameImg} />` the image won't be loaded by the browser until the `img` element is present on the page.

There are some small caveats. Some bundlers will base64 encode the image and inline it directly into the source code. In which case, it will increase your bundle size. However, I believe most bundlers are pretty smart in knowing what it should and what it shouldn't. So I wouldn't worry about that.

Answer (score 0):

yes when you have multiple images it tends to drag your react application so its best you have an online or cloud storage (when you are dealing with a lot of images like if you're building a gallery application ) cloud storage sites like https://cloudinary.com/will be very useful. If you still want to store the images locally make sure you add the lazy loading effect to the div holding the image so users won't think your app is blank you can check https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-loading-skeleton.Goodluck

Answer (score 0):

**No**, loading images locally is not always faster than using external URLs in React app.

### Explanation

The speed of loading images depends on several factors, such as:

- The size and format of the images
- The number and location of the images
- The bandwidth and latency of the network
- The caching and compression strategies of the server and the browser
- The rendering and optimization techniques of the React app

In general, loading images locally means that the images are stored in the same server or domain as the React app, while loading images from external URLs means that the images are fetched from a different server or domain, such as a CDN (Content Delivery Network).

Loading images locally can have some advantages, such as:

- Reducing the number of HTTP requests and DNS lookups, which can improve the performance and security of the app
- Having more control over the quality and format of the images, which can enhance the user experience and accessibility of the app
- Avoiding the risk of broken links or unavailable images, which can degrade the app's functionality and appearance

However, loading images locally can also have some drawbacks, such as:

- Increasing the size and complexity of the app's codebase and bundle, which can affect the loading and parsing time of the app
- Consuming more server resources and bandwidth, which can increase the cost and reduce the scalability of the app
- Limiting the flexibility and diversity of the images, which can reduce the app's adaptability and responsiveness to different devices and scenarios

On the other hand, loading images from external URLs can have some advantages, such as:

- Leveraging the speed and reliability of a CDN, which can deliver the images faster and more efficiently to the users
- Reducing the server load and bandwidth usage, which can save the cost and improve the scalability of the app
- Enabling the use of dynamic and diverse images, which can enhance the app's functionality and appearance

However, loading images from external URLs can also have some drawbacks, such as:

- Increasing the number of HTTP requests and DNS lookups, which can affect the performance and security of the app
- Depending on the availability and quality of the external sources, which can cause broken links or low-quality images
- Losing some control over the format and optimization of the images, which can affect the user experience and accessibility of the app

Therefore, the answer to whether loading images locally is faster than using external URLs in React app depends on the specific context and trade-offs of each option. There is no definitive answer that applies to all cases, and the best practice is to test and measure the performance and user satisfaction of different approaches.

### Examples

To illustrate the difference between loading images locally and using external URLs in React app, here are some examples of code snippets that show how to import and use images in different ways.

#### Loading images locally

One way to load images locally is to import them as modules in the React app, and use them as sources for the `<img>` tag. For example:

```py
// Import the images as modules
import logo from './logo.png';
import banner from './banner.jpg';

// Use the images as sources for the <img> tag
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <img src={logo} alt="Logo" />
      <img src={banner} alt="Banner" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Another way to load images locally is to use the `require` function to dynamically load the images, and use them as sources for the `<img>` tag. For example:

```py
// Use the require function to dynamically load the images
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <img src={require('./logo.png')} alt="Logo" />
      <img src={require('./banner.jpg')} alt="Banner" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### Loading images from external URLs

One way to load images from external URLs is to use the URL as the source for the `<img>` tag. For example:

```py
// Use the URL as the source for the <img> tag
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <img src="https://cdn.example.com/logo.png" alt="Logo" />
      <img src="https://cdn.example.com/banner.jpg" alt="Banner" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Another way to load images from external URLs is to use the `fetch` function to asynchronously fetch the images, and use them as sources for the `<img>` tag. For example:

```py
// Use the fetch function to asynchronously fetch the images
function App() {
  const [logo, setLogo] = useState(null);
  const [banner, setBanner] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://cdn.example.com/logo.png')
      .then(response => response.blob())
      .then(blob => setLogo(URL.createObjectURL(blob)));

    fetch('https://cdn.example.com/banner.jpg')
      .then(response => response.blob())
      .then(blob => setBanner(URL.createObjectURL(blob)));
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <img src={logo} alt="Logo" />
      <img src={banner} alt="Banner" />
    </div>
  );
}
```